# Is it possible to make an sln file in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Recently, I have been learning static libraries in C++, but I have come across a problem in which it  does not seem possible to create an sln file in vs code unlike the simple way visual studio does. Therefore, I began to wonder if it was even possible. Thank you to anyone who answers.

Comment: I just started looking into CMake. It might take your problems away.

Comment: CMake is likely a better solution and if you create your CMakeLists.txt without compiler dependencies you can use the same CMakeLists.txt with Visual Studio Community in the future.

Comment: @drescherjm are there any good tutorials on CMake? I have yet to find a good one, but CMake is definitely what I am looking for; thank you.

Comment: Can't really help with that. I learned CMake from the wiki examples 12 years ago.